# TDD(iOS) SUT fails when I don't make a local variable and run some operation

Tags: ios, swift, tdd, xctest

I have written a test and in my test a `router` spy routes to the next logic of my app. using `start()` function. When I directly call `start` function on my `makeSUT` function test fails. However when I make a local SUT variable and then call start function test passes. I think it might be that my escaping closure `self` gets nil or something however I am not sure. Please do let me know so I can understand what's happening under the hood

Here's the code.

```
class FlowTest: XCTestCase {
    
    var router: RouterSpy!

    func makeSUT(questions: [String]) -> Flow {
        router = RouterSpy()
        return  Flow(questions: questions, router: router);
    }

    // THIS Test FAILS WHEN I DO makeSUT(questions: ["First One", "Second", "Third"]).start()

    func test_startAndAnswerFirstAndSecondQuestion_withTwoQuestions_routeToSecondAndThirdQuestion(){
        let sut = makeSUT(questions: ["First One", "Second", "Third"])
        sut.start()
        router.answerCallback("A1")
        router.answerCallback("A2")
        XCTAssertEqual(router.routedQuestions, ["First One", "Second","Third"])
    }

    class RouterSpy: Router {
        
        
        var routedQuestions: [String] = []
        var answerCallback:  Router.AnswerCallback = {_ in}
        
        func routeTo(question: String,answerCallback: @escaping  Router.AnswerCallback) {
            routedQuestions.append(question)
            self.answerCallback = answerCallback
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my Flow class and my Router Protocol

```
protocol Router {
    typealias AnswerCallback = (String) -> Void
    func routeTo(question: String, answerCallback: @escaping AnswerCallback)
}


class Flow {
    private let router: Router
    private let questions: [String]
    
    init(questions: [String] = [], router: Router) {
        self.router = router
        self.questions = questions
    }
    
    func start() {
        if let firstQuestion = questions.first {
            self.router.routeTo(question: firstQuestion, answerCallback: routeNext(from : firstQuestion))
        }
    }
    
    private func routeNext(from question: String) -> Router.AnswerCallback {
        return {  [weak self] _ in
            guard let self = self else {return}
            if let index = self.questions.firstIndex(of: question){
                if index + 1 < self.questions.count {
                    let nextQuestion = self.questions[index + 1]
                    self.router.routeTo(question: nextQuestion, answerCallback: self.routeNext(from : nextQuestion))
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're chaining the two functions together to create sut, you're not actually creating an instance of the Flow class. Then when you're calling answerCallback() in your test, there's no instance of Flow and therefore no questions Array to pass to the function.

When you initialise sut separately by calling makeSut(questions:) *before* then calling start() you are actually creating an instance of the Flow class as sut, and as such router does have a questions Array to access.